# Sed on line with specific string

Tags: regex, bash, unix, sed, grep

I am having trouble with `sed` utility. I have to substitute regex with a string but only on lines which contains another specific string. Whats more I have to read from file and then modify it by `sed`, not only export substitute values. Here is what I have tried:

```
sed -e '`grep aa test`"s/aa/xx/g test'

sed -n '/aa/p' test | sed s/aa/xx/g

grep aa test | sed 's/aa/xx/g'
```

Comment: Any sample data or example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an adress before `s` command :

```
sed '/aa/ s/aa/xx/g' test
```

`s` command will only apply on lines containing the address pattern

But there is no need to have the same pattern in address and in `s` command.

A better example would be :

```
sed '/bb/ s/aa/xx/g' test
```

Comment: Thank you,  it works! I am happy you did not write RTFM

Comment: This is pretty redundant, though; `s/aa/xx/` will only modify lines with a match, and pass through other lines unmodified.  There are situations where you need an address, but this isn't one of them (and when you do, there is a convenient shorthand; an empty string in the "from" part of the substitution will reuse the address regex; so `/aa/s//xx/`).